# Post HTML code from R to Wordpress

Tags: html, r, wordpress, bash, r-markdown

I succesfully put together an RMarkdown file which produces a nice HTML page. You can see the output here: https://www.crazy-geese.at/updates/schedule.html

What I would like to do now is to post the HTML Code to this page on our Wordpress Site: http://www.crazy-geese.at/spielplann-bbl-2018/

So my specific problem is to get the content to the page. I would need to update it regularly and would like to automate it.

Here are some solutions I see:

- Update the page directly from R (from RMarkdown?) with the html code (that would be awesome)
- Write an external script that does this job (a bash script maybe?)

I'm aware of the packages RWordpress and knit2wp but couldn't figure out how to do it. I also tried iframe but I couldn't get rid of the iframe scrollbars.

Every help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RWordpress` works for me using the following code:

```
if (!require('knitr')) {
  install.packages("knitr")
}
if (!require('devtools')) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}
if (!require('RWordPress')) {
  devtools::install_github(c("duncantl/XMLRPC", "duncantl/RWordPress"))
}

library(RWordPress)
library(knitr)

options(WordpressLogin = c(<user> = '<pwd>'),
        WordpressURL = '<blog_url>/xmlrpc.php')

## new post; memorize the returned id
# knit2wp("<Rmd-file>", title = '<title>',
#         publish = FALSE, action = "newPost")

## update post
knit2wp("<Rmd-file>", title = '<title>',
        publish = FALSE, action = "editPost", postid = <id>)
```

I typically do some further changes in wordpress's interface, which is why I have `publish = FALSE`. You can use `publish = TRUE` if you do not need that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Quick question: The "<Rmd-file>" stands for the location of the rmd-file on my hard disk, right?

Comment: @b_schmidl Correct. All the `<...>` need to be adapted.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But the rmd is the file and not an object in R?

Comment: @b_schmidl Yes, it is the relative or absolute path to the Rmd file.

Comment: Great. Thank you a lot. It works like a charm. Proof here: http://www.crazy-geese.at/spielplann-bbl-2018/ I gave you an upvote but it doesn't show unfortunately because I don't have the reputation

Comment: @b_schmidl You are welcome. The conventional way to say "thank you" on SO is to upvote/accept answers.

Comment: One more quick question. If I run the knit2wp code is then the code in the RMD file executed everytime? Because the RMD file grabs the information from a website. Whole reason why I wrote the script.

Comment: @b_schmidl Yes.